# Docker crashes when renderer process eats up too much memory cypress?

Tags: testing, continuous-integration, cypress, codeship

**Build Error! Build Error: We did not receive any logs from your build for a while so it was stopped**

We detected that the Chromium Renderer process just crashed.
This is the equivalent to seeing the 'sad face' when Chrome dies.
This can happen for a number of different reasons:

- You wrote an endless loop and you must fix your own code
- There is a memory leak in Cypress (unlikely but possible)
- You are running Docker (there is an easy fix for this: see link below)
- You are running lots of tests on a memory intense application
- You are running in a memory starved VM environment
- There are problems with your GPU / GPU drivers
- There are browser bugs in Chromium
  You can learn more including how to fix Docker here:
  https://on.cypress.io/renderer-process-crashed

Answer (score 3):

I just had this problem when running on a docker image in gitlab pipelines. Apparently the default electron browser crashes starting with 6.4.0.
Adding "--browser chrome" fixed it for me.

```
cypress run --browser chrome
```

Comment: I was not using docker and was able to fix this error with your answer. Sometimes, the default electron browser can malfunction.